# Skulpt - Promise not correctly returning when resolving

Tags: javascript, promise, skulpt

I am trying to get the standard input from a textarea, and I am close to finding the solution but I have found that my promise is not correctly returning a value.

```
 function sInput() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
         $("#outputField").on("keyup", function(e){
             if (e.keyCode == 13){
                console.log("test");
                resolve("5")
                resolve("random test");
             }
         })
      })
   }
```

The code above is what I have so far (Which does not return "5" or "random test"), but if I change the function to

```
 function sInput() {
        return "5"
   }
```

**Then "5" is correctly returned. Why is my promise not returning the value correctly?** This is a continuation from [This example for more exact information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43733896/wait-for-an-event-to-occur-within-a-function-in-javascript-for-skulpt)

More code :

```
function runit() { 
   var prog = document.getElementById("inputField").value; 
   var mypre = document.getElementById("outputField"); 
   mypre.innerHTML = ''; 
   Sk.python3 = true;
   Sk.pre = "outputField";

   Sk.configure({ output:outf, 
                  read:builtinRead,
                  inputfun: sInput,
                  inputfunTakesPrompt: true});



   var myPromise = Sk.misceval.asyncToPromise(function() {
       return Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>", false, prog, true);
   });

   myPromise.then(function(mod) {
       console.log('success');
   },
       function(err) {
       console.log(err.toString());
   });
}
```

Comment: a promise resolves exactly once ... second resolve is meaningless - secondly `sInput` returns a **Promise**, does whatever calls it (or `inputFun`) know how to use Promises? (i.e. .. `.then`)

Comment: I am not entirely sure on that one, I just assumed it had the .then because on the linked example, they seemed to react as if it worked. I am using the assumption that the .then is implemented.

Comment: Why is resolve only called once? If i press enter continuously the print("test") is called multiple times

Comment: different promise each time

Comment: Is there a way to check that the .then() are implemented? I'm having the exact problem as this person shown here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43733896/wait-for-an-event-to-occur-within-a-function-in-javascript-for-skulpt) but it seemed to work for him?

Comment: I guess the fact the issue there was that they were not returning a Promise means it's a different issue ... you are returning one, and that is what is apparently expected - so, perhaps there's something else you're "doing wrong"™

Comment: https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt/blob/653b39afb10135160d1de8cbb3e49881f7a6e45e/src/env.js I'm looking at there source code, it seems the original inputfun returns window.prompt(), does this mean a promise won't work? If so, how did that previous question work

Comment: I'm entirely confused now, I've edited the edited the code and I can make it notice random test, because I get a python error  with converting bases because of int("random test"). But when I place in "5", im not getting the same behaviour as if I do return "5"