# Using Skulpt and Splinter for Python web application with Turtle?

Tags: python, splinter, brython, skulpt

I'm currently developing a web application where the primary function is Python's Turtle. When I started doing this I used Skulpt to be able to visualize and run my python code on the website, and it worked great. However, I need to give my python code an input from a form in the HTML-file. So I tried using Splinter for that problem, but it did not work, it seems as though the Python code stopped running when I wrote "from splinter import browser".

Does anyone know if Splinter is not compatible with Skulpt or if there is another way I may go about to do this?

Answer (score 0):

splinter is not implemented in skulpt. You can write it yourself. Take a look at "Third Party Modules" on http://www.skulpt.org/

Another way is to change "input()":

```
Sk.configure({
        inputfun: function (prompt) {
           return window.prompt(prompt);
        },
});
```

Here is an interesting post about change the input 
[Wait for an event to occur within a function in Javascript for Skulpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43733896/wait-for-an-event-to-occur-within-a-function-in-javascript-for-skulpt)

Comment: Thanks! However, after some thought I think I will be trying out Brython as it seems easier to work with DOM API and such.